# When calling a second program via load, gets reads from ARGV[0] of original program

Tags: ruby, argv

Consider a file named `weird1.rb`:

```
load 'weird2.rb'
```

and `weird2.rb`:

```
p = gets.chomp
puts "Got input: #{p}"
```

When I run `weird1.rb` without any argument, `gets` reads the user's input from the console:

```
c:\a\ruby>weird1.rb
test
Got input: test
```

When I run it with an argument, `gets` reads from the argument given (`someRandomArg` and `weird2.rb`, respectively in the cases below):

```
c:\a\ruby>weird1.rb someRandomArg
weird2.rb:1:in `gets': No such file or directory - someRandomArg (Errno::ENOENT)

c:\a\ruby>weird1.rb weird2.rb
Got input: p = gets.chomp
```

Why is `weird2` reading from `weird1`'s argument? This seems unexpected; `gets` is supposed to read from `stdin`, not a file. What is happening, and how do I fix this?

Comment: (this is a greatly simplified version of the problem, by the way; the purpose of the original code was to do some pre-setup before executing a different file)

Comment: @sawa Quite the cleanup you did there, thanks! (I think the title was a bit too vague though, so I edited it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The load part has nothing to do with it.  The same thing should happen if you directly call weird2.rb with and without an argument.

The effect you're seeing is that gets functions like a unix filter, which means it will read from STDIN if no file is specified, or else the file(s) provided via the command line.

If you're doing some preprocessing via weird.rb, then remove any args off of ARGV via shift before loading weird2.rb, like such:

```
my_arg = ARGV.shift
# do stuff with my_arg
load 'weird2.rb'
```

Comment: Wait, but I'm not calling `weird2` with any arguments. I'm just calling `weird1` with arguments; are they being passed on? In any case, how do I make `gets` read from stdin again?

Comment: If weird.rb needs the argument for something, have it shift it off of ARGV:

Comment: so, `load ARGV.shift`? That did it, mind editing your answer to include that?